# Node and Edge Click Action With NetworkX

Tags: networkx

I want to create a graph where I want display information based on node and edge click event.  I am not able to resolve using Pyvis and NetworkX.

Do not see support for click event with Pyvis https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/interaction.html#

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for events:

https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html#Events

Here's an html snippet that creates a graph and attaches a couple event listeners:

```html
<div id="mynetwork"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-network/standalone/umd/vis-network.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    { id: 1, label: "Node 1" },
    { id: 2, label: "Node 2" },
    { id: 3, label: "Node 3" },
  ]);

  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    { from: 1, to: 3 },
    { from: 1, to: 2 },
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById("mynetwork");
  var data = {
    nodes: nodes,
    edges: edges
  };
  var options = {};
  var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
  network.on('click', function(properties) {
    if (properties.edges.length > 0) {
      alert(`you clicked these edges: ${properties.edges}`)
    }

    if (properties.nodes.length > 0) {
      alert(`you clicked these nodes: ${properties.nodes}`)
    }
  })
</script>
```

Note that it treats clicking a node as clicking that node and its edges, so you'll need some logic to get the specific types of interaction you're looking for.

Comment: That looks like the docs for visjs. Looks like Poster is looking for using this in the context of pyviz.